# Jest failing with unhelpful error message when throwing new Error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I'm calling this function in my code and throwing an error:

```
myFunction(message) {
    if (!message) {
        throw new Error('No Message')
    }
}
```

and the test:

```
it.only('should throw error if no message', () => {
   library.myFunction() // no message
   expect(global.opener.postMessage).not.toHaveBeenCalled()
})
```

But Jest is just pointing at the word `new` and the test is failing with no other message. How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried explicitly *expecting* that call to throw an error, see https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tothrowerror

Comment: @jonrsharpe I could assert for that too but I want to just assert my function is not called, surely I can do that ?

Comment: You can, but if you want the test to keep *running* then *something's* going to need to catch the error - it could be you, just try/catch, or it could be Jest using the expectation.

Comment: ah ok. that makes sense. I catch the error in another component though

Comment: *What* other component? Before it gets to the test function? Give a [mre].

Comment: it's ok I actually solved the test now thanks to your help. I have wrapped the function call in `try` and then the expectation in `catch`. worked all good

Comment: Note if you're doing that you need to explicitly fail the test if an error *isn't* thrown, otherwise your expectation is never reached and the test passes anyway.

Comment: well I removed the `.not` in my test and it failed indicating that there is no false positives?

Comment: That's not what that indicates. That indicates that your test would tell you if the function was called *before* the error gets thrown. However what if no error gets thrown? If the expectation is in the catch block, it's never even reached, you're not actually even checking whether or not the function gets called. That's the false positive. This is why it's better to use the actual expectation, because then it fails explicitly if no error is thrown and you only check whether the function got called if that basic requirement for met.

Comment: my function always gets called before the error is thrown. and it'll always throw an error on this one condition. if the condition is false, it skips the if block and proceeds to call the rest of the function. jest is failing on the calling of the function so I need to put that in the `try` part and expect in the `catch`

Comment: *"my function always gets called before the error is thrown"* - what? If postMessage is called *before* myFunction errors then your current expectation (and [mre]) is wrong. *"it'll always throw an error on this one condition"* - maybe it *should*, but this is why we write tests, to validate that it *does*. The point stands - if you manually try and catch, you need to explicitly fail the test if the error isn't thrown, because otherwise there's a regression that would never get caught (or, more simply/mechanically, a logical path through the test function *with no expectations*).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your test is *crashing*, rather than failing, because the error thrown by `myFunction` is never caught. There are two broad solutions to this:

1. Let Jest catch it, using the built-in [`toThrow`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tothrowerror) expectation for errors:

   ```
   it.only('should throw error if no message', () => {
       expect(() => library.myFunction()).toThrow()
       expect(global.opener.postMessage).not.toHaveBeenCalled()
   })
   ```

   Note that in this case you need to wrap the call to `myFunction` in a function, to defer execution so that Jest can handle the error (otherwise the error is thrown before `expect` can be called and you're back in the same position).
2. Catch it yourself, using `try`/`catch`, and explicitly ensure that one expectation is reached during the test:

   ```
   it.only('should throw error if no message', () => {
       expect.assertions(1)
       try {
           library.myFunction()
       catch (err) {
           expect(global.opener.postMessage).not.toHaveBeenCalled()
       }
   })
   ```

   *Without* [`expect.assertions`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#expectassertionsnumber), if a future change means that the call to `library.myFunction` does not throw an error, then no expectation is ever reached inside the test and it silently passes. It's important to ensure that either all logical paths through your test have expectations, or you explicitly check the expected number are reached.

Comment: ah ok this makes sense! and my test passes with it. I would query 1 thing you said said above ""my function always gets called before the error is thrown" - what?"" why is that so baffling? my function gets called and then if a condition is true, I throw an error. anyway the rest makes sense so will upvote and and mark as correct. feel free to upvote the question, it helps me out (and I did see this issue in github on jest page and it didn't seem anyone found a really good solution)

Comment: @RedBaron if by "my function" you meant myFunction then yes, but that seemed redundant to point out - if you never call it, of course nothing happens. So I assumed you meant postMessage, the function that you're trying to verify does not get called. Also if you found something in your research you should include that **in your question**.

Comment: will update, the question when I get a moment later. cheers