# How to handle throwing Exceptions in jest

Tags: javascript, typescript, exception, jestjs, nestjs

I have created a method that throws exception when provided passsword doesn't match regex. I tried to handle it in Jest

```
  it('Should not insert a new user cause password do not match regex', async () => {
    jest.spyOn(usersModel, 'create').mockImplementationOnce(() =>
      Promise.resolve({
        name: 'some name',
        email: 'some email@email.com',
        pass: 'some pass',
      } as IUser)
    )

    const newUser = await usersService.create({
      name: 'some name',
      email: 'some email@email.com',
      pass: 'some pass',
    })
    expect(newUser).toThrow()
  })
```

I tried also `toThrow('message of error')`
and `toThrow(new BadRequestException())`
None of them works.

This is my jest error

```
 UsersService › Should not insert a new user cause password do not match regex

    Password does not match regex

      49 |     const emailRegex = /[^@ \t\r\n]+@[^@ \t\r\n]+\.[^@ \t\r\n]+/
      50 |
    > 51 |     if (!pass.match(passRegex)) throw new BadRequestException('Password does not match regex')
         |                                       ^
      52 |     if (!email.match(emailRegex)) throw new BadRequestException('Email does not match regex')
      53 |
      54 |     const saltRounds = 10

      at UsersService.create (users/users.service.ts:51:39)
      at Object.<anonymous> (users/users.service.spec.ts:135:21)
```

Comment: You need to pass a _function_ to expect it to throw, otherwise the error happens _before_ the `expect` is reached: https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tothrowerror. Or you can use `.rejects`: https://jestjs.io/docs/asynchronous#resolves--rejects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `.resolves` matcher in your expect statement (and it's recommended one):

```js
it('Should not insert a new user cause password do not match regex', async () => {
  jest.spyOn(usersModel, 'create').mockImplementationOnce(() =>
    Promise.resolve({
      name: 'some name',
      email: 'some email@email.com',
      pass: 'some pass',
    } as IUser),
  );

  // Remove `await` keyword, because you will pass a promise in the expect function
  const newUser = usersService.create({
    name: 'some name',
    email: 'some email@email.com',
    pass: 'some pass',
  });

  // Add `await` keyword and `rejects` matcher with the `toThrow`
  await expect(newUser).rejects.toThrow('Password does not match regex');
});
```

Also, you can use a simple `try/catch` statement (but, please don't use it):

```js
it('Should not insert a new user cause password do not match regex', async () => {
  expect.assertions(1)

  jest.spyOn(usersModel, 'create').mockImplementationOnce(() =>
    Promise.resolve({
      name: 'some name',
      email: 'some email@email.com',
      pass: 'some pass',
    } as IUser),
  );

  // Add `try/catch` statement
  try {
    const newUser = await usersService.create({
      name: 'some name',
      email: 'some email@email.com',
      pass: 'some pass',
    });
  } catch (e) {
    expect(e.toString()).toMatch('Password does not match regex');
  }
});
```

Comment: You should **not** use `try`/`catch` like that in tests; if the error isn't thrown, no expectation is ever hit, so the test passes. In that case you need to use e.g. `expect.assertions` to make sure the test fails in the right case, as I show in https://stackoverflow.com/a/62513421/3001761.

Comment: Hey @jonrsharpe. Thanks for the comment. Fair point, I've updated my answer.